# librosa.load() takes too long to load(sample) mp3 files

Tags: python-3.x, audio, mp3, sampling, librosa

I am trying to sample (convert analog to digital) mp3 files via the following Python code using the `librosa` library,  but it takes too much time (around 4 seconds for one file). I suspect this is because `librosa` doesn't support `mp3` and hence uses the slower `audioread` to sample `mp3`

Code:

```
import time
import librosa

s = time.time()
for i in mp3_list[:10]: # list of mp3 file paths, doing for 10 files
    y, sr = librosa.load(i)

print('time taken =', time.time() - s)
```

`time taken = 36.55561399459839`

I also get this warning:

```
UserWarning: "PySoundFile failed. Trying audioread instead."
```

Obviously, this is too much time for any practical application. I want to know if there are better alternatives to this?

For comparison, it only took around `1.2` seconds total time to sample 10 same-sized `wav` conversions

Answer (score 4):

So the warning kind of hints it. The Librosa developers addressed a similar question in [this GitHub question](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1015):

> This warning will always occur when loading mp3 because libsndfile
>   does not (yet/currently) support the mp3 format. Librosa tries to use
>   libsndfile first, and if that fails, it will fall back on the
>   audioread package, which is a bit slower and more brittle, but
>   supports more formats.

This is confirmed in the [Librosa-code](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/b59bb4404b0c5bf2667e3e864e73783857d887b1/librosa/core/audio.py#L126): `try ... except RuntimeError ...`

So what you can do in this case is either implement your own `load()` that directly uses `audioread` to avoid the time wasted in the first block of `librosa.load()`, or you can use a different library such as [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub). Alternatively, you can use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to [convert your mp3 to wave](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919788/convert-mp3-file-to-wav-using-the-command-line) before loading them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in Pydub you can sample by following this https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown#audiosegmentget_array_of_samples right? I mean using AudioSegment.from_file().get_array_of_samples() ?

Comment: Also, I think the link I mentioned can't be used for sampling. I can't even find where to mention the sampling rate. Do you know how Pydub can be used for sampling?

Comment: So when using the pydub lib you essentially read your audio as an `AudioSegment` object which has the attribute `frame_rate`. So you can do the following: `mp3_audio = AudioSegment.from_file("path/to/audio.mp3", format="mp3")` and then `sr =  mp3_audio.frame_rate`. Please let me know if this pydub version is faster than the Librosa alternative (in your question), as this would be a good edit for the answer.

Comment: I am not sure if by sampling you mean changing the sampling rate, but if so that is possible using: `newly_sampled_audio = mp3_audio.set_frame_rate(new_sampling_rate)`

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Yes, what I wanted was to resample to a new sampling rate. There is an improvement in time with `pydub` but still not comparable to loading `wav` files. It took `sound = AudioSegment.from_file("path/to/audio.mp3", format="mp3").set_frame_rate(8000)` `1.26` seconds on a file while `y, sr = librosa.load("path/to/audio.mp3", sr=8000)` took `1.77` seconds